# Changing the android.jar source when changing the min SDK version in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I have an Android project in Eclipse that I need to change the min SDK version from 10 (Android 3) to 4 (Android 1.6). Changing this in the AndroidManifest file is no problem, but this does not, however, change the android.jar reference. It remains stuck in Android 3.0 and I can't figure out how to change this without starting a new project.

I have tried refreshing and cleaning but that doesn't help. I've also tried playing around in Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries that seems to contains this info, but can't find a way to change it here either.Does anyone know to change it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to change this without starting a new project.

Project > Properties > Android, then change the checked API level in the Project Build Target table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I knew it was something really simple.